# Adding iptables route on openvpn connect

Tags: iptables, bash, openvpn, scripting

I have my openvpn server up and running and I push certain routes to my clients via the ccd directive, I would like to know how I can update the iptables based on the ccd files when the client connects.

So lets say my ccd for client1 is :

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.45 255.255.255.0
push 'route 10.10.0.45'
```

and I want to add this to the iptables.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.45 -d 10.10.0.45 -j ACCEPT
```

and then

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

If someone can point me in the right direction would be much appreciated, im fairly newb with bash scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into an **OpenVPN** configuration many scripts, which receive many parameters from the server as **environment variables**: cf. [Reference Manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/#scripting-and-environmental-variables).

You are mostly interested in the `up`, `down` scripts to insert the `DROP` rule at server startup and shutdown and the `client-connect` and `client-disconnect` script for per client rules. You need to modify your server config to contain:

```
# Allow user scripts
script-security 2
# up/down script
up /etc/openvpn/updown.sh
down /etc/openvpn/updown.sh
# Client connect/disconnect
client-connect /etc/openvpn/client.sh
client-disconnect /etc/openvpn/client.sh
```

1. Your `/etc/openvpn/updown.sh` script will create a `OPENVPN` and link it from the `FORWARD` chain:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IPT=/usr/sbin/iptables
# 'script_type' contains the type of the script
if [ "$script_type" = "up" ]; then
  $IPT -N OPENVPN
  $IPT -A FORWARD -j OPENVPN
  $IPT -A OPENVPN -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.10.0.0/16 -j DROP
else
  $IPT -F OPENVPN
  $IPT -D FORWARD -j OPENVPN
  $IPT -X OPENVPN
fi
```

2. You client script `/etc/openvpn/client.sh` will be more complicated: while the public and private IP addresses of the remote client are contained in the `ifconfig_remote` and `ifconfig_pool_remote_ip`, you will need to parse the ccd file to find out which routes did you send to the client:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IPT=/usr/sbin/iptables
# We need to split the line into words as bash would, by
# interpreting the double quotes, hence the 'eval'.
function parse_ccd_line() {
  eval "local line=($1)"
  # If the first word is 'push' return the second one.
  if [ "${line[0]}" = "push" ]; then
    echo "${line[1]}"
  fi
}

# Your ccd_dir so we don't need to parse the OpenVPN
# server config file too.
ccd_dir=/etc/openvpn/ccd

if [ -f "$ccd_dir/$common_name" ]; then
  # We read the "$ccd_dir/$common_name" file line by line:
  while read line; do
    # We split the argument of every 'push' directive into 'cmd' and 'arg1'
    # If you need more arguments, the array 'push_opt' contains them.
    push_opt=($(parse_ccd_line "$line"))
    cmd=${push_opt[0]}
    arg1=${push_opt[1]}
    # We use just the 'route' commands
    if [ "$cmd" = "route" ]; then
      if [ "$script_type" = "client-connect" ]; then
        $IPT -I OPENVPN -s "$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip" -d "$arg1" -j ACCEPT
      else
        $IPT -D OPENVPN -s "$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip" -d "$arg1" -j ACCEPT
      fi
    fi
  done < "$ccd_dir/$common_name"
fi
```